# inheritance with recursive method override

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class A:
    def m(self, v):
        for i in range(v):
          print("A")
          self.m(v-1)

class B(A):
    def m(self, value):
        print("B")
        super(B, self).m(value)

B().m(3)
```

Output: `B A B A B A`

Expected output: `BAAAA`

On class A, the self object is of B and it's calling method m of class B, but I don't want this to happen.

I know I can change the method name, but that is a constraint, I can not change the name of method.

Comment: That's because `self` is an instance of `B`, not `A`. If you want `A.m` to *always* call `A.m`, you have to call `A.m(self, v-1)` explicitly . More likely, though, you should not be overriding `m` in the first place, but defining a different method that *uses* `self.m`.

Comment: As a workaround, you could redefine `self.m` to be the `super` method just before the call to `m` in `B`, then fix it back after the call returns.  You'll need to keep the old `m` in a variable `old_m` for safekeeping

Comment: @chepner OP addresses both of these things in the question, I think.

Comment: Who imposed this constraint?

Comment: @Him, how can I do the thing that you said?

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily overwrite `self.m` in your instance of `B`.  This makes it so that you don't need to change the definition of `A`

```
class A:
    def m(self, v):
        for i in range(v):
          print("A")
          self.m(v-1)

class B(A):
    def m(self, value):
        print("B")
        mB = self.m
        self.m = super(B, self).m
        self.m(value)
        self.m = mB

B().m(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a contrived example but you could use a keyword argument that defaults to 0 and a conditional expression that only prints the "B" if the argument is 0, and then increment the argument on subsequent calls.

For example:

```
class A:
    def m(self, v, count=0):
        for i in range(v):
            print("A")
            self.m(v-1, count=count+1)

class B(A):
    def m(self, value, count=0):
        if count == 0:
            print("B")
        super().m(value, count=count +  1)

B().m(3)
```

output:

```
B
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```